# Array Like Objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm wondering how jQuery constructs its array-like object. The key thing I'm trying to work out is how it manages to get the console to interpret it as an array and display it as such. I know it has something to do with the length property, but after playing a bit I can't quite figure it out.

I know this has no technical advantage over a normal array like object as in the example below. But I think it's an important semantic element when users are testing and debugging.

A normal Array like Object.

```
function foo(){
    // Array like objects have a length property and it's properties use integer
    // based sequential key names, e.g. 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 just like an array.
    this.length = 1;
    this[0] = 'hello'
}
// Just to make sure add the length property to the prototype to match the Array 
// prototype
foo.prototype.length = 0;

// Give the Array like object an Array method to test that it works     
foo.prototype.push = Array.prototype.push

// Create an Array like object 
var bar = new foo;

//test it 
bar.push('world');

console.log(bar);
// outputs 
{ 0: 'hello',
  1: 'world',
  length: 2,
  __proto__: foo
}
```

Where as jQuery would output

```
var jQArray = $('div')

console.log(jQArray);

// outputs
[<div></div>,<div></div>,<div></div>,<div></div>]
```

If you run

```
console.dir(jQArray)

// Outputs

{ 0: HTMLDivElement,
  1: HTMLDivElement,
  2: HTMLDivElement,
  3: HTMLDivElement,
  4: HTMLDivElement,
  context: HTMLDocument,
  length: 5,
  __proto__: Object[0]
 }
```

The proto of the jQuery object is especially interesting since its the Object and not jQuery.fn.init as would be expected, also the [0] indicates something as this is what you get when you.

```
console.dir([])
// outputs Array[0] as the object name or Array[x] x being the internal length of the
// Array
```

I have no idea how jQuery has set it's proto to be Object[0] but my guess is that answer lies somewhere in there. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but couldn't you create your object then set its prototype to Array.prototype?  It will then be an array-like object?  Or no?

Comment: well as far as I know that will make it a normal array. But I also want to avoid that since I don't want to add all the Array methods to my object, in order to avoid confusion. As some Array methods will actually return a new Array, so when a user uses one of those methods all the other methods that where attached to my array like object will be lost.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The object has to have `length` and `splice`

```
> var x = {length:2, '0':'foo', '1':'bar', splice:function(){}}
> console.log(x);
['foo', 'bar']
```

---

and FYI, the `Object[0]` as the prototype is for exactly the same reason.  The browser is seeing the prototype itself as an array because:

```
$.prototype.length == 0;
$.prototype.splice == [].splice;
```

Comment: No need for splice if you don't need the object to print as an array with console.log(). length and properties like 0,1 will suffice to use the array methods.

Comment: @zyklus Do you happen to know if this is part of the ECMA spec (array-like objects) or is this a browser nicety?

Comment: @Usagi - AFAIK this has nothing to do with ECMA script and is just a random dev tools thing.  There are a lot of "array-like" objects in JS, both in the language and user-created, so it's useful to show them as arrays if they implement some minimum subset of `Array`, this is just what the devs picked.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
function foo() {
  this.push('hello');
}
foo.prototype = [];

var bar = new foo();
console.log(bar.length); // 1
console.log(bar); // ["hello"]
```

Comment: That has the same effect as the response I gave @JohnStrickler. I don't want to add all the Array methods to my Object to avoid confusion as some array methods actually return a new Array. So any other methods I attach to the object will be lost, when they are used.

Comment: jQuery object uses Array as its prototype. I think you can redefine this methods so they will return new foo object instead of regular array.

Comment: @Andrey M. - Please don't go saying stuff that you don't know for sure.  jQuery does ___not___ use `Array` as it's prototype.  It uses `push`, `sort`, and `splice` from `Array`, but that's it.

Comment: I took another look up the prototype Chain of the jQuery object and cannot find Array defined anywhere within it.