# What makes a jQuery object show up as an array in Chrome's Developer Tools?

Tags: jquery, arrays, google-chrome, instance

I'm wondering how it's possible that jQuery objects show up as an array in the console log of Developer Tools in Chrome.

E.g. if I execute `$('<a>')`, what I see in the console log is:

```
[<a>​</a>​]
```

But the following statements are false:

```
var a = $("<a>");

Array.isArray(a);   // false
a instanceof Array; // false
```

I tried to modify jQuery and see what happens, and one thing that was surprising is that removing `length` from the jQuery function removes the array notation:

```
length: 0, // commenting this line removes array notation
```

Instead, it then shows up as (arrow is that solid one to expand):

```
> jQuery.jQuery.fn.jQuery.init
```

But, if I try to make my own constructor which is supposed to be displayed in array notation, it does not work:

```
var test = function() { this.length = 0 };

new test();

// Logged (arrow is same one as before):
// > test
```

So I'm wondering what in the jQuery code makes Developer Tools show instances as an array. What property/function/thing is added to jQuery that makes Developer Tools handle it as an array when displaying an instance?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/:

> Many methods, both in jQuery and in JavaScript in general, return objects that are array-like. For example, the jQuery factory function $() returns a jQuery object that has many of the properties of an array (a length, the [] array access operator, etc.), but is not exactly the same as an array and lacks some of an array's built-in methods (such as .pop() and .reverse()).

Basically, The object has to have `length` and `splice` properties to be array-like. Here is a relevant SO question: [Array Like Objects in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599071/array-like-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: To prove it you can run `console.log({'0': 'asd','1': 'asd', length: 2, splice: function () {}})` in the console.

Comment: anyone knows why does Chrome treats `splice` differently? fyi this only works in Chrome but not other browser.

Answer (score 4):

You probably know this, but `console.log` is not displaying passed content "as is", it is trying to be "smart" and does some post processing. If you want to see original object "as is", there is `console.dir` method.

Comment: I know about `console` capabilities; I was just wondering how jQuery made itself show up as an array while it isn't one.