# Possible logic error or comparator issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, comparator

I am doing the following:

```
if ($('#selectYears option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]') != null || $('#selectYears option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]') != [] ) {
      console.log("inside if")
      $('#selectYears option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').remove().appendTo($('#selectYears'))
    } else {
      console.log("inside else")
      $('#selectedYears option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').remove().appendTo($('#selectYears'))
    }
})
```

If i do `$('#selectYears option[value="my value"]')` in Chrome's console I get []. But I am printing out inside if (therefore my check is failing). I need to get into the else in this case. Where am I wrong?

Comment: a jQuery selector cannot possibly be null or an empty array as it always returns a jQuery object. If you're trying to check if the element exists, use `length`, otherwise please explain a little more about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A jQuery selector never returns `null` or an array, it returns a jQuery object. It looks like an array in the console because it has properties that make it "array-like", but it isn't actually an array and will not compare equal to `[]`. For more about this, see

[What makes a jQuery object show up as an array in Chrome's Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261670/what-makes-a-jquery-object-show-up-as-an-array-in-chromes-developer-tools)

If you want to know if anything was matched, use `.length`:

```
if ($('#selectYears option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').length != 0) {
```