# What is the actual type of the object jQuery is returning

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

Just like `$` itself is not simply a user defined object (it is, at its base, a function and that is why you can use the `()` operator on it and it inherits all the functions from `Function.prototype`) what is the actual Javascript `type` of the so-called [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery) object?

It has to be one of the standard array-like objects because you can use the `[]` operator on it, something you can't even do on strings in IE8 (and no, you can't, not on the Object `String`. You can on string literals before they're boxed).
So again, its not a user defined object (NB there's no such thing as a `jQuery` object, its written in raw javascript somewhere along the line). I have a feeling its a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) (or equivalent in browsers that don't have `NodeList`).

A reason you might have noticed this is you've added methods to the `Array` prototype, and you discover the function doesn't exist on a set of nodes found by jQuery!

So is anyone intimate with jQuery enough to share this lower level info with me? Or is there a short, exhaustive list of array-like objects in Javascript that I can test the jQuery object against till I find out which one it is myself?

---

The reason I ask this, instead of assume that jQuery is just adding elements to the object, using indexes as property names (I.e. `obj[0] = x;`) is because of how the Chrome dev tools and Firebug display them.
[image: dev tools displaying Array, jQuery and Array-like objects]
This shows dev tools displaying Array, jQuery and Array-like objects, and that there is at least some magic behind what jQuery is doing.

---

EDIT

It's not a `NodeList`. If it helps; inspecting it in Chrome shows that it is of type `jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[0]` with a `__proto__` describing itself as `Object[0]` (which has all the jquery methods). Anyone explaining what and how jQuery is doing would be greatly thanked. I'm going to look at jQuery's source now.

And as for the image, it isn't simply an overridden `.toString()`.

```
$('').toString == Object.prototype.toString //true
$('').toString == Array.prototype.toString //false
```

Comment: similar to, but lower level than [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302428/what-does-jquery-actually-return). I'm not interested in the abstraction

Comment: It's a function. Once you select elements with it, what is returned is an array-like object, in that it's really just an object, but it looks smells and feels like an array. that is why it has some array methods, but not all of them.

Comment: the `[]` operator is not a 'method'. You can't give it to anything you want; it is not a user-defined object that has some array methods.

Comment: The objects returned by invocations of the jQuery function are just regular objects. As in any object, you can access it's properties using bracket notation (i.e., `obj[prop]`). jQuery uses numeric property names (which are actually strings), adds a length property and, if I'm not mistaken, splice. That's enough to create an array-like object.

Comment: just to improve the SO community: _this_ is how you write a question.

Comment: @Hashbrown all objects in JavaScript can make use of `[]`. This is perfectly valid JavaScript: `var a= {}; a[0] = 'hi';`. This is because all objects in JS (including functions and arrays) are dictionaries of key value pairs where the key is always a string. Arrays have some sugar on top of them to make them feel/look more "array like"

Comment: I understand that, my assumption was the jQuery wasn't adding each element to the objects like `output[0] = el1; output[1] = el2;` etc. For some reason I thought there was more magic than that.

Comment: I've not looked at jQuery's code, but applying an array to the jQuery object would be doable, so they get the numeric indices without manually creating the,.

Comment: @MattGreer, the reason I had overlooked that possibility for the jQuery object is that whenever I inspect jQuery objects, they appear to be treated specially by the debugging tools (see newly added image)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is it possible to query jQuery('div') like an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793036/why-is-it-possible-to-query-jquerydiv-like-an-array) or [How does the jQuery pattern work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143590/difference-of-the-value-prototype-and-property)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### What is a jQuery object?

The `$()` or `jQuery()` function returns a `jQuery` object. It is not an `Array` and not a `NodeList`, and not in any way derived from either of those. It is an `Object` created with the `jQuery` constructor (which is actually the `jQuery.fn.init()` function). This object is very much like any other `Object` created with `new SomeConstructor()`, or even a plain object literal.

When you call `$()` or `jQuery()` without a `new` operator, it [automatically does a `new` for you](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/f66d53c85643e703a8e37d9ca9375dd386a60cda/src/core.js#L32):

```
jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init
    // constructor 'enhanced'
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
},
```

The `jQuery` object is somewhat "array-like" in that it has properties with numeric indexes and a `.length` property, but these are just properties set directly in the object in the jQuery code. It also has a number of properties and methods that come from its prototype, which is `jQuery.fn` or `jQuery.prototype` (`jQuery.fn` is merely a reference to `jQuery.prototype`; they are the same object.)

You can see an example of this in the [jQuery code that wraps a DOM element when you use `$(element)`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/f66d53c85643e703a8e37d9ca9375dd386a60cda/src/core.js#L135):

```
// HANDLE: $(DOMElement)
} else if ( selector.nodeType ) {
    this.context = this[0] = selector;
    this.length = 1;
    return this;
} ...
```

In this bit of code, `selector` is actually a DOM element, and the code stores that element in `this[0]` and sets `this.length` to `1`. This is why you can use `[0]` and `.length`, simply because the object has these properties that were explicitly set.

#### Why does a jQuery object display like an Array?

There is some magic involved here, but the magic is in Firebug and the Chrome Developer Tools. They both look for two specific properties to decide to display an object as if it were an array:

1. A `length` property which is either a number or a string containing a number.
2. A `splice` property which is a function.

If the object has both those properties, it is displayed as an array.

You can test this by pasting the following line into either the Chrome DevTools or Firebug:

```
({ splice:function(){}, length:0 })
```

Chrome displays:

```
[]
```

Firebug displays:

```
Object[ ]
```

Remove either property and it will display as an object.

It doesn't matter if these properties are in the object itself or its prototype. You can paste this code into either console and it will display the same array-like notation as the code above:

```
function A(){}; A.prototype = { splice:function(){}, length:0 }; new A;
```

You can add an element to your "array":

```
({ splice:function(){}, length:1, 0:'test' })
```

Now Chrome displays:

```
["test"]
```

and Firebug displays:

```
Object[ "test" ]
```

Note that the Firebug display is not *exactly* the same as what it displays for an actual `Array`. Firebug puts that `Object` prefix in front of the array-like display to let you know that it's not an actual `Array`.

It does that on jQuery objects too. If you enter:

```
$(document.body)
```

Firebug displays:

```
Object[ body ]
```

You can click the word `Object` to get the full object-style display of the jQuery object instead of the array-like display.

Chrome doesn't make this distinction; it displays an `Array` or an array-like `Object` the same way.

So there's the magic. It's really nothing special in jQuery, except that the object it returns does have the `length` and `splice` properties. The `splice()` method is on the prototype and the `length` property may come from the prototype (for an empty "array") or more often from the jQuery object itself.

Those two properties trigger the real magic: a hack in the DevTools and Firebug to try to provide a more useful display for objects like these.

#### Bragging rights :-)

A bit of historical trivia: I was actually responsible for this part of jQuery's architecture. The very first version of jQuery in early 2006 didn't work like this. The jQuery object didn't have a `.length` and `[0]`, `[1]`, etc. properties. Instead it had a "private" array of its own, and you had to use `.get(n)` to fetch values from that array.

I thought it would be more convenient to have direct array-like access to the elements and came up with the idea of setting the `.length`, `[0]`, `[1]`, etc. properties so it would work like a read-only array.

Comment: I never stated it derived from `Array`. In fact I stated the opposite. However I am not wrong in assuming it derives from *one of* the array-like object types because it has *operators* indicative of those types (properties can be assigned, yes. operators (ie `[]`); not so much). The only way jQuery could get around this is assign the index property for each of the found elements. Eg `jQueryObj = new Object(); jQueryObj[0] = foundEl1; jQueryObj[1] = foundEl2;` etc

Comment: I meant no offense, sorry. I've added some more information to the answer which should help clarify. The jQuery return object really is nothing more than a standard JavaScript `Object` created with a `new` operator.

Comment: I honestly skipped around the notion that jQuery would iterate each index, adding them as properties to itself, because I thought it'd be wasteful. I assumed it was getting an array using sizzle or something and then make it its own (by overwriting the prototype or something else fancy). I guess this keeps it simple and I wish I kept an open mind enough to see that jQuery used the simplest method from the begining

Comment: @Hashbrown: In javascript, the `[]` operator works on `Objects`, not `Arrays`. The only reason Arrays can use the `[]` operators is because arrays are themselves objects. The `[]` operator works just like the `.` operator to access properties and methods in objects but the `[]` operator expects a string or number and the `.` uses barewords.

Comment: this is noted by @MattGreer in a comment to the question, and I know this, it was my assumption in the comment above yours which was my error, not this. I thought the jQuery object inherently was a collection and wasn't a simple object with properties enumerated (like `['0'], ['1'], ['2']` etc). In fact, if you read the last sentence of the first comment to this answer you would see that I understood this.

Comment: @MichaelGeary, please see my added image which adds to my confusion. Why would debugging tools display the jQuery object as an Array yet objects constructed to look like Arrays are treated like Objects still?

Comment: I'm impressed by your determination to get to the bottom of this! (I mean that sincerely.) I experimented a bit and discovered what is really going on. See updated answer for details.

Comment: so `splice` was the key! Thanks for that @MichaelGeary. (for some reason I didn't get a notification on your comment, sorry for the untimely, well-deserved tick)

Answer (score -2):

my understanding is a sub class of Array, which inherited from Array Class and has its own method

changes above:

it's not sub class of Array. But it made from Array, but after Array object created, jQuery alter the object prototype with jQuery its own prototype,then finally it become jQuery object which is Array-like object.

Comment: then it should pick up all the functions from `Array.prototype`. There are no classes and is no subclassing in Javascript (if you're referring to it in a way you would talk about Java)

Comment: thanks for answering though, I see you ask no questions yet take the time to answer others' anyway, good on you *thumbs up* :)

Comment: javascript has no java-like class but has its own prototype class which you can do thing like class do.  check this article from jQuery creater: [link](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/)

Comment: this a example to extend method of one particular array, but not impact the other array object.[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/898BF/1/)

Comment: if you read jQuery's source code you will found jQuery is class/function which return a array, then jQuery will prototype all jQuery's methods on this array. so jQuery object is array with Array methods and also jQuery methods.

Comment: Yes modifying the array object of one array doesn't affect all arrays. That would be really poor language design. I, however, am talking about this scenario http://jsfiddle.net/898BF/3/

Comment: where might I find the source? If I understand what your saying jQuery is doing [this](http://jsfiddle.net/898BF/4/)? But overwriting the prototype doesn't seem to work, so it can't be a plain `Array` with a different prototype

Comment: jquery source code is hosted in github [jquery core](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/maste/src/core.js)

Comment: assign methods to original javascript class is very bad design. your scenario is not good practice. (unless the library is ployfill/back-Compatible  library). one third part library call prototype.js assigned methods in original javascript class, so it is not recommended because this reason. but jQuery use magic way to inherit all the methods from array but not assign methods on array prototype, that is good way to do.

Comment: you mean [this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js) (your link is broken). and what I meant to do in my fiddle was [this](http://jsfiddle.net/898BF/5/), so I guess it is possible, but I dont know about cross browser.

Comment: I know what isn't good practice, and that isn't the purpose of the question, it's used here as a test for type. The question calls for an explanation of the magic, not a declaration that there is some

Comment: -1, it doesn't subclass array at all.

Comment: you overwrite b.prototype with only method, so b is array-like object without any array methods. the others' array will still have that function