# Getting the count of divs which are children of some divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the count of some divs. Here is my page structure as a picture. I want to get the count of cityUnderText divs.

[image]

I am using these script codes but I m getting **0** but I need just **6**.

```
var h = $("div.cityUnderText").length;
alert(h);

var h = $(".cityUnderText").length;
alert(h);
```

Comment: You are using the wrong case.  `var h = $(".cityundertext").length;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$(".cityundertext").length`.

[JavaScript is a case-sensitive language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Case_Sensitivity_in_class_and_id_Names).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Case_Sensitivity_in_class_and_id_Names Class and id attributes are case-sensitive.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the link! I will add it to the answer then.

Answer (score 1):

```
var count=$(".cityundertext").size(); // jquery's method
```

OR

```
var count=$(".cityundertext").length;
```

**Or be more specific**

```
var count=$("#content_pnlDestinations .cityundertext").size(); // jquery's method
```

OR

```
var count=$("#content_pnlDestinations .cityundertext").length;
```

Comment: Well, thanks but isn't it also available to native javascript ? Or does jquery has it's own.

Comment: Native arrays have a `length` property, and so does the jQuery object (which disguises itself as an array).

Comment: So I'm just assuming that jQuery use `size()` method to return the `length` property of an array and `length` belongs to native javascript, this is my understanding. Is this wrong, anyway ? Thanks.

Comment: `length` is just a property name, what belongs to native JavaScript is the array object. I don't know how jQuery implements its `size` method, but it probably just returns the current object's own `length` property (no arrays involved). See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599071/array-like-objects-in-javascript) for a discussion on array-like objects in js.

Comment: You're right. `size()` just returns `length` [jsapi.info](http://jsapi.info/jquery/1.7.1/jQuery.fn.size)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll('div > div').length`, which is faster than jQuery, because it's native (2x to 3x faster).