# How is $('h1') logging to the web console as an array in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, logging, browser, console

If you do `console.log($('some selector'))` in the browser, it returns what looks like an array (first line):

[image: picture from latest version of chrome web console on Github project page]

But notice that it's not an `instanceof Array`, but it's actually [the `jQuery` object](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/ae20e732f02c7e3bdd76324979b1a816c567ec22/src/core.js#L6).

When you do `console.dir($('h1'))`, it shows it's actually the jQuery object.

The question is, how are they making it look like it's an array in the web console?  I noticed in the jQuery source [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/ae20e732f02c7e3bdd76324979b1a816c567ec22/src/core.js#L74) they add reference to a few Array and Object methods, and [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/ae20e732f02c7e3bdd76324979b1a816c567ec22/src/core.js#L199) they add `toArray` (and slice and others) to the `jQuery` object.  Is the web console somehow checking for these methods and if it finds one (`toArray`, `indexOf`, `slice`, etc.), it prints it as an Array?  I would like to get this behavior out of any custom object, such as the `Ember.ArrayProxy`.  Currently when you log the `Ember.ArrayProxy` it shows `> Object` or whatever, but it would be nice to show it as an array.

Any ideas?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599071/array-like-objects-in-javascript.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You make your object inherit `Array` using the prototype, like so:

```
function SomeType() {
    this.push(16);
}

SomeType.prototype = [];
SomeType.prototype.constructor = SomeType; // Make sure there are no unexpected results

console.log(new SomeType()); // Displays in console as [16]
```

And, of course, all jQuery objects are instances of the `jQuery` function/constructor, so that's how jQuery does it. As a bonus, because of the inheritance, you get all the methods from `Array`, and the indexing that comes with it too!

Comment: Nice! Well I just did some other tests, and if you do this: `var x = {length: 0, splice: Array.prototype.splice}`, then `x` will look like an Array.  Strange...  It requires specifically those 2 properties it looks like.

Comment: @LancePollard: Interesting, seems to work cross-browser too! Although the inheritance method does have the advantage of `new SomeType() instanceof Array` being `true`.

Comment: Stoked to finally have a cross-browser way to extend the Array, thank you.

Comment: BTW how did you test this cross browser so quickly?

Comment: P.S. You're 14, hardcore! :) Going to change the world.

Comment: @LancePollard: I've actually known it for a while :) Used it in a library a few years ago. So I didn't actually test it now. (And thanks!)

Comment: @minitech - How the heck did you make the tic tac toe on your profile??? *confused...*

Comment: @Derek: I just read the `Referer` header using PHP and take the `?add` parameter out of it, while keeping track of sessions. Don't tell anyone :)

Comment: It still allows for user input after a win/loss, make it work with a win-tie-lose count and I'll spend a couple hours on it. :) (sorry for off-topic, nice answer btw)

Comment: *league of legends account voice* Godlike!

Comment: @minitech I don't think jQuery really inherits from the array prototype, it implements `length`, `splice` and maybe other methods.