# Confused About Resig Curry Example And "arguments" Object

Tags: javascript

In [this article](http://ejohn.org/blog/partial-functions-in-javascript), John Resig discusses this snippet for currying:

```
Function.prototype.curry = function() {
    var fn = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return function() {
      return fn.apply(this, args.concat(
        Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
    };
  };
```

I am confused about the expression `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)`.

1. Here "arguments" is the "this" argument to Array's slice() method, but "slice()" requires an argument itself, so I would think you'd need to do something like `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, <someIndex>)`. I don't understand how that code can be working as is.
2. According to [the docs on "arguments"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments), "arguments" is not actually an Array, but only an array like object.  How are we calling "slice()" on it?  And if I put in the code `console.log(arguments.slice())` I get an error saying that the object does not have a slice method.

What's going on here?

Comment: Resig voodoo, all your code is belong to John !

Comment: @Xander, No it doesn't discuss that explicitly, although I think that snippet may come from the prototype library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer to first question:**

If you call slice on an array without arguments, it will just return a copy of the array. `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)` does just the same, but operates on the `arguments` object, returning an array.

**Answer to second question:**

We can call slice on `arguments` because it's a "generic" method (see the note [here](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.10)). When you pass the `arguments` object as `this`, `slice` will treat it as an array. Since `arguments` is an [array-like object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599071/array-like-objects-in-javascript) that contains a `length` property, it just works.

Comment: @Pointy: Are the docs wrong in listing the startIndex as required? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: It seems you commented on the wrong answer! :) But I think I know the answer to your question: the specification says that the first argument is converted to an int with `ToInteger`, which happens to return 0 when you pass undefined. See http://es5.github.com/#x9.4 and http://es5.github.com/#x9.3

Comment: Actually, not a mistake.  You get notified automatically, but I had to @Pointy to notify him as well.  So I just did that instead of asking the same question in both of your answers :)

Comment: @Pointy too: Why does calling slice directly on the arguments object *not* work?  http://jsfiddle.net/Xcn32/1/ -- Everything is now clear given bfavaretto's answer to my last comment, except this mystery remains....

Comment: @Jonah Pointy won't be notified because it's not his answer, and he is not participating in the comments here. More details on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Comment: To answer the second question: because the arguments object is not an array, so does not have a slice method on its prototype chain. @Jonah

Answer (score 3):

The argument to `.slice()` is optional. If it's absent, the function just returns a copy of the original array (or array-like object).

The `.slice()` function just cares about the presence of a "length" property on the `this` object.  Thus, because "arguments" does have a "length" property, `.slice()` is happy.

Comment: Pointy, please see the comments to bfavaretto's answer for a followup question (I had the same question for both of you).  Thanks.

Comment: @Jonah are you all set now?  Looks like bfavaretto has provided typically wonderful answers but feel free to ask more questions. The `arguments` object is a strange thing.