# Use jQuery map function's result in a chain

Tags: jquery

When I call:

```
var result = inputs.map(function(){ return $(this).val(); });
```

`result` contains an array like:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'buz']
```

I want to join result:

```
result.join(', ');
```

works, but

```
var result = inputs.map(function(){ return $(this).val(); }).join(', ');
```

gives

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

My question is rather theoretically - why cannot I access result array in a chain and I have to assign it to the variable before working on the result ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of jQuery's `.map` method is not an array, it's a jQuery collection. Use [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/#get2) to return an array of the collection contents.

```
var result = inputs.map(function(){ return $(this).val(); }).get().join(', ');
```

Comment: Thanks - indeed the type of result is `object` but console displays it as an array.

Comment: Yeah, jQuery makes its collections look like arrays in the console. It confused me the first time I ran into this.

Answer (score 1):

Because the returned value is a jQuery wrapped array which doesn't have `join` method, you should get the array using jQuery `get` method.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599071/array-like-objects-in-javascript) is a related question.