# Cant use prototype if constructor return object

Tags: javascript

Can somebody explain me this:

```
var foo = function() {
  if (!(this instanceof foo))
    return new foo();
  return {}; // Object
};
foo.prototype.myPlugin = function () { // Uncaught TypeError: foo(...).myPlugin is not a function
  alert("bar")
};

foo().myPlugin();
```

but:

```
var foo = function() {
  if (!(this instanceof foo))
    return new foo();
  return ""; // string, number, etc
};
foo.prototype.myPlugin = function () {
  alert("bar") // --> "bar"
};

foo().myPlugin();
```

as i see, jquery works like first code sample, and returns array of finded DOM nodes. But when i try return array, i have this error too.

Comment: jQuery? there is no jQuery here or Dom nodes. I know why the first code piece throws the error but I'm confused about the purpose of the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you return an object from a constructor that will be returned instead of the object created by `new`. If you return any other type, your return value will be ignored and the new object will be returned instead.

jQuery doesn't return an array of DOM elements. [The jQuery object is just array-like itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6599071/772035). It has some numeric properties, a `length` property, and a `splice` method, which is all it takes for you to be able to access elements like `obj[0]` and for a console to log it like an array.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way the javascript is. In a constructor if you return a primitive type it returns the constructed object instead. Simply the primitive value is ignored. If it returns an object it returns that object.

For example

```
function ReturnsObject(){ return {}; }
function ReturnsPrimitive(){ return 5 // 'string'; }
console.log( new ReturnsObject()) // {}
console.log( new ReturnsPrimitive()) // ReturnsPrimitive{}
```